# Finding the optimal way to combine text in chunks

Tags: python, optimization, combinatorics

I'm trying to find the optimal way to generate text chunks, based on some constraints.

I have a JSON structure with that looks as follows:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "parent_id": null,
  "text": "This is level 1, id 1",
  "blocks": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "parent_id": 1,
      "text": "This is level 2, id 2",
      "blocks": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "parent_id": 2,
          "text": "This is level 3, id 3",
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "parent_id": 2,
          "text": "This is level 3, id 4",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "parent_id": 1,
      "text": "This is level 2, id 5",
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to combine multiple `text` fields into chunks taking the following into consideration:

1. Only combine `text` fields if that results in a chunk with less than X characters (i.e. 50).
2. Combine chunks starting from the deepest nested elements.
3. Minimize the number of chunks generated.
4. Order should be preserved.

For the provided JSON sample, these are the expected chunks (and order):

```py
chunks = [
  ["This is level 1, id 1", "This is level 2, id 2"],
  ["This is level 3, id 3", "This is level 3, id 4"],
  ["This is level 2, id 5"]
]
```

Note that the element with `id=5` isn't put together with the element with `id=2` despite them being at the same depth, because that would break the order. The only way to combine them would be if the sum of the characters of the elements 2, 3, 4, and 5 is less than 50.

Any ideas how to implement this using Python?

I've tried to generate text chunks recursively by traversing the JSON tree from the deepest nested elements to the root, but I've failed to make it work. I haven't been able to get that output.

Comment: seems depth does not matter, so flatten your whole structure to single list of strings, preserving order. Represent all your strings as ints (their length). And then answer yourself a question - do you really need **optimal** way, or just good enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

```py
def get_texts(data):
    yield data["text"]
    for block in data.get("blocks", []):
        yield from get_texts(block)

def get_chunks(data, max_len=50):
    chunks = [[]]
    chunk, chunk_len = chunks[0], 0
    for text in get_texts(data):
        text_len = len(text)
        if chunk_len + text_len <= max_len:
            chunk.append(text)
            chunk_len += text_len
        else:
            chunk = [text]
            chunks.append(chunk)
            chunk_len = text_len
    return chunks
```

The `get_texts` generator function is a simple depth first recursive unnesting function. And the `get_chunks` function takes the output of the `get_texts(data)` generator that clusters the texts as long as the sum of the string lengths of the whole cluster doesn't exceed the threshold `max_len`.

If you apply this to the following string (your string isn't JSON-complient)

```py
import json

json_str = """{
  "id": 1,
  "parent_id": null,
  "text": "This is level 1, id 1",
  "blocks": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "parent_id": 1,
      "text": "This is level 2, id 2",
      "blocks": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "parent_id": 2,
          "text": "This is level 3, id 3"
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "parent_id": 2,
          "text": "This is level 3, id 4"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "parent_id": 1,
      "text": "This is level 2, id 5"
    }
  ]
}"""

data = json.loads(json_str)
chunks = get_chunks(data)
```

then you'll get

```py
[['This is level 1, id 1', 'This is level 2, id 2'],
 ['This is level 3, id 3', 'This is level 3, id 4'],
 ['This is level 2, id 5']]
```

Comment: @python_user Yes, I saw that, but imho it contradicts the _"Order should be preserved."_. I'll wait to see if OP sheds some light on it.

Comment: Thank you. This works well. If you increase the chunk size to `5000`, the output should be a single chunk.